# How do you get the number of clicks from a button using e.getActionCommand()?

Tags: java, swing, button

I have 'n' amounts of buttons, according to the user's decision. Whenever I click on the button I want it give me the amount of times it has been clicked. The tricky thing is that I didn't set any name to the buttons, the user did. So my question is, how would I check if the 'countAmount' is 1 or more using the e.getActionCommand()?

I'm really stuck on this problem, if anyone could help that would be great! This is part of my program, any help would be great!

```
private static int countAmount = 0;

public Example()
{
    str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the name of the new button?"); 
    JButton b18 = new JButton(str);

    //The actionlistener stuff
    countAmount++;

    if (countAmount % 2 != 0)
    { 
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand() + "was clicked, count is even");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The button was clicked, count is odd");
    }

    if (countAmount.(e.getActionCommand) == 1)
    {
       System.out.println("This button has been clicked " + countAmount + " times);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not necessarily what an `ActionListener` should be used for. You should be using something like a `MouseListener` with a `MouseEvent`.

Comment: @Zizouz212: no, I'd use an ActionListener for this if he is simply counting button press count.

Comment: To the original poster, you'd be better served if you created and posted a decent [mcve]. But for a quick solution, consider using an array of int or a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to hold the counts of all the buttons.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is find how many counts the button I clicked on has. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Yes there is -- but **again** show more code, preferably a [mcve], so we can show you!

Comment: I added more code, but again all I'm asking is if the 'countAmount' of the e.getActionCommand is 1, "do something". Thanks!

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `//The actionlistener stuff` is the whole thing you need and you are not showing it. For the 3rd time, post a [mcve]..

Comment: @user1803551: I've been trying to convince him of this, but to no avail.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No kidding...

Answer (score 2):

1. Put your buttons into an `ArrayList<JButton>`.
2. When the button is pressed, don't worry about the ActionCommand.
3. Instead get a reference to the actually button itself by calling `getSource()` on the ActionEvent parameter in your button's ActionListener.
4. To find out which button was pressed, iterate through the ArrayList of buttons with a for loop.
5. When you find a match, use the index of the button in the array list to increment an `ArrayList<Integer>`
6. Alternatively you could simply create a `HashMap<JButton, Integer>` and simply increment the Integer value associated with the source JButton key.
7. For more detailed answer, please post a real and valid [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program.

Comment: How would I find the button in the arraylist if i don't know its name? Since the user is writing the name. I'll edit more of my code so it makes sense.

Comment: @D.Maximov: you'd simply iterate through the ArrayList using a simple for loop. And understand that the "name" is not important here. Rather the ***reference*** is.

Comment: So, is getSource() like getActionCommand()? What's the difference?

Comment: @D.Maximov: `getSource()` returns a reference to the component that initiated the event, ... here the pressed JButton while `getActionCommand()` returns the button's actionCommand String. You keep adding code that really does not show the essence of your problem. If you want code help with your problem, please consider posting some serious code, again please read the link that I've provided and try to post code that comes close to the specification.

Comment: @D.Maximov: again my answer states, `"in your button's ActionListener"`. Again, you're not showing us any of this stuff.

Comment: I'm starting to get this. I'm just new to this stuff. How would I add my button to an arraylist? Would I do it when the user named the button? Or declare them before?

Comment: @D.Maximov: I would do it on GUI creation when I create my JButtons and add the buttons to the GUI.

Comment: Should I declare a size to my arraylist? Because I don't know how many buttons the user will use.

Comment: @D.Maximov: read up on ArrayLists since that is in fact the **main** advantage that they have over using arrays -- you don't have to pre-declare their size at all. Consider them as similar to using a magic variable-sized array.

Comment: Our class recently studied ArrayLists, but I'm not sure how to add a button to my list. Is it "arrayList.add(button)" ?

Comment: @D.Maximov: this is the point where you move away from StackOverflow and over to your compiler and start playing with your code. Try it. See what happens. Experiment. Play.

Comment: I have, for like 2 days now, but i'll try, thanks for the help!